# Docker container failed to run with pacemaker resource agent

Tags: docker, centos7, high-availability, pacemaker

I have a 2 node cluster configured on `CentOS 7.6` with latest `docker` and `pacemaker` packages.

I am currently trying to provide HA for couple of containers but after configuring `pacemaker` resource `ocf:heartbeat:docker` all containers fail to run. I have tried with a simple `alpine` container without any other parameters except the ones required by resource agent but it still fails to run.

Can someone explain what can be the reason for this and how to troubleshoot the issue.

following output was captured from `crm_mon`.

```
[root@drbd-node01 ~]# crm_mon -Arf1
Stack: corosync
Current DC: drbd-node01 (version 1.1.19-8.el7_6.4-c3c624ea3d) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Fri Sep 13 19:50:54 2019
Last change: Thu Sep 12 17:25:22 2019 by hacluster via cibadmin on drbd-node01

2 nodes configured
4 resources configured

Online: [ drbd-node01 drbd-node02 ]

Full list of resources:

 blog-vip       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started drbd-node01
 Clone Set: blog-drbd-svcs-clone [blog-drbd-svcs]
     Started: [ drbd-node01 drbd-node02 ]
 test_docker    (ocf::heartbeat:docker):        FAILED drbd-node01 (Monitoring)

Node Attributes:
* Node drbd-node01:
* Node drbd-node02:

Migration Summary:
* Node drbd-node01:
   test_docker: migration-threshold=1000000 fail-count=78996 last-failure='Fri Sep 13 19:50:54 2019'
* Node drbd-node02:
   test_docker: migration-threshold=1000000 fail-count=1000000 last-failure='Thu Sep 12 17:25:53 2019'

Failed Actions:
* test_docker_start_0 on drbd-node01 'unknown error' (1): call=348928, status=complete, exitreason='Newly created docker container exited after start',
    last-rc-change='Fri Sep 13 19:50:53 2019', queued=0ms, exec=1098ms
* test_docker_start_0 on drbd-node02 'unknown error' (1): call=94, status=complete, exitreason='Newly created docker container exited after start',
    last-rc-change='Thu Sep 12 17:25:53 2019', queued=0ms, exec=489ms
```

Comment: do you any error or some information that you can show, do you try crm_mon -Arf1 ?

Comment: Hi @c4f4t0r, I have updated the post as you suggested. it seems the resource is getting failover continuously from one node to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after tinkering a bit around the `pcs resource create` command. The issue was due to the way I provided values to the `run_opts` argument. Had to encapsulate the answer within `""` to run it correctly.

```
pcs resource create blog_db_docker ocf:heartbeat:docker image=mariadb reuse=true allow_pull=true run_opts="--volume-driver drbdmanage -v blogdb:/var/lib/mysql --expose=3306 --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123" op monitor interval=30s
```